# Is it possible to extract a sentence from a Word document that has a word in bold?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to build a list of terms by extracting a sentence that contains a word that is bold in a Word document.  Is that possible?  I know how to search for words in bold. But I don't know how to select the sentence that has the bold word.

I added some code to copy and paste the found text into a new document. It was working fine but now it's not. I don't know why. This is what I have now:

```
Sub Extract_terms()
    With Selection.Find
        .Format = True
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.Expand wdSentence
        Selection.Font.Bold = False 'added to prevent infinite loop
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("list.docx").Activate
        Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        Windows("Chapter 3.docx [Compatibility Mode]").Activate
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1    
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I notice that when the line Do While Selection.Find.Execute runs, the cursor freezes instead of finding the bold text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `wdSentence` as a unit for `Selection.Expand`. Here's an example:

```
Sub test()
    With Selection.Find
        .Format = True
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.Expand wdSentence
        Selection.Font.Bold = False 'added to prevent infinite loop
    Loop
End Sub
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdunits(v=office.14).aspx) is a list of all the possible units you can use for the `wdUnits` enumeration.

Comment: this worked well - but now it's not working.  I added some lines to copy the selected sentence to another docuemnt and it was working fine but now it's not.  Don't know how I broke it but it's not working.  This is what I have now.:

Comment: I would have to guess it is related to some find settings, you'll have to ask a new question and post some images of the text you are searching more than likely to get a good answer. Best of luck

Comment: Once a `Selection.Find` settings are set they carry throughout the duration of the application (they may carry beyond that but IDK), so it is wise to do as @mohammedaldefrawy did and try and reset everything, though I will say that is not everything you need to reset.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way is to record a macro of that search contains the wanted criteria and then take the code to your program and modify it as you want.

ex:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Font.Bold = True
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "YOUR WORD"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchKashida = False
    .MatchDiacritics = False
    .MatchAlefHamza = False
    .MatchControl = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
```